# Obtain reference to view created by Prism Navigation

Tags: .net, wpf, prism-4

In an application using the Prism framework, I'm adding a view to a region using the navigation features of the region manager like this:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("DetailRegion",
    New Uri("EditUserView" + query.ToString(), UriKind.Relative))
```

Once the navigation has completed, I'd like to obtain a reference to the new that has been created. This is so that the view can be closed automatically when its parent is closed.

Is there a method in Prism (or otherwise) to do this? This is Prism 4.1?

Comment: Youd should be able to to do this RegionManager.Regions["DetailRegion"].ActiveViews(). This will give you all active views for this region. The active view for this region should be the one that you just navigated to so .First() will get it.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Genius! I'll give this a try and see if it works. I'll put it in the callback function specified in RequestNavigate (as it's asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

Youd should be able to to do this

```
RegionManager.Regions["DetailRegion"].ActiveViews()
```

This will give you all active views for this region. The active view for this region should be the one that you just navigated to so .First() will get it.